# Python world analog of Rails encrypted credentials feature (to store secrets securely)

Tags: python, security, encryption, credentials

Are the Python analogs of [encrypted credentials Rails feature](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-6-2/)?

Quote from [Rails Guides on subject](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials):

> Rails stores secrets in `config/credentials.yml.enc`, which is encrypted and hence cannot be edited directly. Rails uses `config/master.key` or alternatively looks for the environment variable `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]` to encrypt the credentials file. Because the credentials file is encrypted, it **can be stored in version control**, as long as the master key is kept safe.

> To edit the credentials file, run `bin/rails credentials:edit`. This command will create the credentials file if it does not exist. Additionally, this command will create `config/master.key` if no master key is defined.
>
> Secrets kept in the credentials file are accessible via `Rails.application.credentials`.

My idea is:

- to have all the secrets encrypted in repository;
- to have locally only `master.key` (or only one env variable);
- to once pass manually to production server `master.key`;
- then pass other secrets by git through automated deployment process.

Comment: As is done in Rails, you would do most or all of this *outside* Git. The only way Git itself would take part in the encrypt/decrypt process is if you set up smudge and clean filters for the encrypted files. (Rails appears to do all of this outside Git, which is generally easier and means Git doesn't even enter the picture.) Note, however, that if you're looking for some existing Python tool that does this, such a question is off topic for StackOverflow (consider superuser.com or similar instead).

Comment: @torek you are right about Git. Git itself is out of the picture. Just not Python tool but python approach to this. Similarly as it done in Rails.

Answer (score 2):

There is https://github.com/nzaillian/django-encrypted-secrets that works like Rail's encrypted credentials, but I haven't seen it used in any projects I've worked on.

Usually I see environment variables being used and accessed using `os.environ`:

```
import os

os.environ['API_USER']
```

The [django-environ](https://github.com/joke2k/django-environ) package is also very popular and is often used together with `.env` files.

I haven't used it myself, but [dynaconf](https://www.dynaconf.com/) also seems popular.